# RAISE NOTICE from trigger to QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, trigger

I work on vue postgresql made with table,
so for save I have to use trigger.

My trigger do a lot of thing and I have to send message to the user to make him understand what happend.

But QGIS only show RAISE EXCEPTION and not the RAISE NOTICE, but the 
RAISE EXCEPTION stop the trigger and nothing append.

How to send a message from a trigger to the user of QGIS?

Comment: Seems to be implemented in 2015: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/20374. Can you provide details to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: also need the version of QGIS.

Comment: Qgis 3.8 ,I see it was done in 2015 but i dont know how make it work maybe a Qgis option?

Comment: `IF ( nbaffect > 0) THEN
  RAISE NOTICE 'error message';
  continue := False;`
but whith this QGIS show nothing exept if i put RAISE EXCEPTION , but with raise exception the trigger stop and its not what I want